# How to redirect to the same page with custom params using search form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, search, parameters

I have a page (`get 'records/:id' => 'records#show', as: 'show_record'`), with a long list of records of table "Page". I would like to be able to refine this list based on entered params. How can I add params to the end of the current url using a search form?

To illustrate:

```
<!--tentative search form
<%= form_tag show_record_path(@record), :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:x] %>
  <%= submit_tag "search" %>
<% end %>
-->

<!--set filter-->
<% if params[:x].nil? %>
  <% @pages = @record.pages %>
<% else %>
  <% @pages = @record.pages.where("name LIKE ?", params[:x]) %>
<% end %>
<!--list-->
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
  <%= page.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your illustration you're suggesting doing this logic in the view. I would suggest doing any filtering in your controller. I would suggest having a look at [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form). [This one](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) is also very good.